FormatException: Unexpected character in Flutter
When i click login an error appears: 'Invalid response format from the server'
and FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
but i wanted to go to another page Accpage
it didn't want to change the page!
I use wampserver64 for mysql database
***this is the function login to send the data to php and the php code:
Future<void> login() async {
    final String login = loginController.text;
    final String password = passwordController.text;

    try {
      // Send login request
      final req = await http.post(
        Uri.http('192.168.56.1','/app_data/data.php'),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: jsonEncode({
        'login': login,
        'password': password,
        }),
      );
      if (req.statusCode == 200) {
        try {
          final decodedData = json.decode(req.body);
          if (decodedData['message'] == 'Login successful') {
            setState(() {
              error = '';
            });
            final user = decodedData['user'];
            // Naviger au compte de user:
            // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => Accpage(
                          login: user['login'],
                          //photo: user['photo'],
                        )));
          } else {
            setState(() {
              error = decodedData['message'];
            });
          }
        } catch (e) {
          if (e is FormatException) {
            // ignore: avoid_print
            print("FormatException: ${e.message}");
            setState(() {
              error = 'Invalid response format from the server';
            });
          } else {
            rethrow; // rethrow if it's not a FormatException
          }
        }
      } else {
        setState(() {
          error = 'Failed to connect to the server ';
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      error = 'Error:$e';
    }

<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$msg=json_encode(['message'=>'entered']);

try{
$login=$_POST['login'];
$pass=$_POST['password'];
error_log("***Received login: $login, password: $pass");
if (!$login || !$pass){
    $msg=json_encode(['message' => 'Enter your login and password']);
}
else{
    $dns ="mysql:host=localhost;dbname=authentif";
    $user ="root";
    $mdp = "";
 
    $cnx=new PDO($dns,$user,$mdp);
    $cnx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $req=$cnx->prepare('select * from utilisateur where login=? and password=?');
    $req->execute(array($login,$pass));
    $res=$req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(!$res){
        $msg=json_encode(['message'=>'No account found']);
    }else{
        $msg= json_encode([
        'message'=>'Login successful',
        'user'=>[
            'login'=>$res['login'],
            //'photo'=>base64_encode($res['image']),
        ]]);
    }}
}catch(Exception $e){
    $msg=json_encode(['message'=> 'Error: '.$e->getMessage()]);
}
echo $msg;


You receive a 200 from your php code, which is fine first of all. So I would say, the error is in your flutter code. Did you try to debug it? What is the output, if you print the req.body immediately before you try to json.decode() it?

when i add a print nothing is printed !

i got this on the debug console:
I/flutter (10020): Response body: *********entree **{"message":"Login successful","user":{"login":"mayssa"}}
I/flutter (10020): FormatException: Unexpected character
